# PHP Slim v3 add cookie in response headers

Tags: php, cookies, localhost

We are using PHP Slim v3 as a backend and Angular as a frontend. Both the apps are running on the same localhost with different ports.

In one of the api call, we would like to add the cookie in response headers.

Had used following methods to add the cookie to slim php response header but addition has not been successful until yet.

1) Use slim php v3 setCookie (API throws a server error setCookie called on null). Had invoked setCookie on $app, $this, $response but nothing worked.

2) Use diff methods from library (https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies).

3) Use $response->withAddedHeader("Set-Cookie", "hello=world");

I would like to add "Set-Cookie" to the response headers.

e.g.

```
$app->post("/cookie", function($req, $response, $args) {

  // add code to set cookie in response headers.
  return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson(["status" => "success"]); 
});
```

Any help on this part would be appreciable.

P.S. This is my hello world program for setting cookie :-).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The problem is with the local API server.

Used [PHP Slim PSR7 Cookie library](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-fig-cookies) library with another working localhost API server to set the cookie in the response header. Also, using specific client address for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` instead of using a general *.

Thanks for the help Community!